# Prices tab is gone in my custom product type

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created a custom product type but it appeared that it lost "Prices" tab.

On the screenshot, on the left are the tabs for default product, on the right - my new product's tabs. How do I restore the prices tab?

[image: tabs - default product vs custom]

In my config.xml I have

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <type>
            <email_marketing translate="label" module="ContactologyProduct_LogProductUpdate">
                <label>Email Marketing</label>
                <model>ContactologyProduct_logproductupdate/product_type</model>
            </email_marketing>
        </type>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably the attributes that should appear in the `Prices` tab are not applied to your custom product type.
Edit for example the attribute with code `price` (or `tax_class_id`) and you will see a field called `Apply to` with multiselect with all the product types. Only some of them will be selected (your new type is not included).

You have to edit each attribute and add your product type in the list.

I suggest doing that from an upgrade script so it is portable to your staging or live server.

Here is how you can do that:

```
$fieldList = array(
    'price','special_price','special_from_date','special_to_date',
    'minimal_price','cost','tier_price','weight'
); //list here all the attribute codes from the price tab
foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
    $applyTo = explode(',', $installer->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to'));
    if (!in_array('email_marketing', $applyTo)) {
        $applyTo[] = 'email_marketing';
        $installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to', implode(',', $applyTo));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Edit for example the attribute with code price" - where? I don't add my product via install script, can't I just edit `config.xml`?

Comment: @van_folmert. I was talking about `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribtues`. The attribute `Price` is set to be used only for a few product types. So it is not applied for yours. The same goes for all the attributes in the `Prices` tab. And if a tab does not contain attributes it is not shown.